# What happens when user comes down to low reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

I was offering bounty to some good unanswered questions, but I suddenly realized what happens if I come down to below 50 reputation or below 125 reputation points (minimum reputation points required to comment and downvote).

Is it still possible to comment or downvote in that case?

Comment: Yes you lose the privileges.